# Access to the path 'c:\tridion\log\appie.txt' is denied

Tags: preview

We are getting error 'Access to the path 'c:\tridion\log\appie.txt' is denied.' during page preview.

Comment: This question doesn't meet the necessary standards to be on this site. You can improve it by adding enough detail and clearly explaining your problem, including what you've tried yourself to solve it. Otherwise, I'm afraid it will get deleted very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You have not given very much information, however [a google search](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22c%3A%5Ctridion%5Clog%5Cappie.txt%22) for this path throws up a hit on DD4T templating code base - so I guess you are using DD4T and there is a file system access problem (either this folder does not exist, or the Tridion service account does not have permissions to write to it).